# Vim unable to navigate generated tags with Exuberant Ctags

Tags: vim, tags, vi, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I am not able to navigate using vim and ctags. While tying to navigate with ctags in vim, i get the following error:
E429: File "../../../folder_name1/folder_name2/filename.h" does not exist

When i check the tag file, the path exists.

The tag is generated with the following command in the location where the tag is saved:

ctags -R --tag-relative=yes --line-directives -f my_tags ../../../../my_lib/*

One additional question: What would be the output of ctags? Will it have the actual folder and file names or will it be modified form of folder names? I see the folder names are somewhat obfuscated in the generated file.

Comment: The problem is probably related to using parent directories `..` and the wildcard `*`. Can you just `cd` to the top of your tree and simply run `ctags -R .` directly? Also, why not just generate a file named `tags` which Vim will recognize and know how to handle directly? (Why use `-f my_tags`?)

Comment: There are three tag files generated and all of them are checked in at a common tag folder. Then this is added in the vimrc using set tags command. This is the reason for using -f my_tags.

Isn't it supported to have hierarchical references using ../../ format?

Comment: I just think you're making it way harder than it needs to be... Have you tried to use the normal setup? Does it work for you or not?

Comment: I tried two things, and i can more or less confirm that there is a bug in exuberant ctags if a relative path is used as input.

1. I tried generating the tags with universal-ctags and hierarchical paths and it worked perfectly
2. I tried generating the tags without giving the ../../hierarchical paths, and it worked.

Comment: Can you actually do `:e ../../../folder_name1/folder_name2/filename.h` from the same buffer where you got the error? What is the output of `:echo &tagrelative`?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. The issue is in the generated tag file. The folder path is not correct. For example, the folder path is like manipulated. For example, instead of the actual path, i see some thing like `../../../fldr_nae1/fldr_na2/filename.h`. Somehow it is changing the actual folder name to a short hand name!